# PHP ssh2_sftp_mkdir creating permission incorrectly

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions, umask

```
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/home/site',0774);
```

I am using the above to create a folder remotely but instead of the folder having permissions `774` it is getting set as `754` meaning that it is not writeable by the group.

Answer (score 0):

The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using umask().

Comment: Well, the manual states that ssh2_sftp_mkdir function is similar to using mkdir() with the ssh2.sftp:// wrapper, so I think it will.

Comment: So I have tried $old = umask(0);
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, $folder,0775);
umask($old); which ends up with permissions of 755

Comment: Does it allow you to change directory permissions later with ssh2_sftp_chmod?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that php function [`ssh2_sftp_mkdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-mkdir.php) is for some reason affected by system `umask` settings, and the problem is this isn't documented.

For example, if you do

```
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/home/site',0774);
```

and `umask` on your system is set to `022` (as it is default on most Linux distributions), you will end up with created directory `site` that has permissions `754` (`drwxr-xr--`)

It is possible to alter `umask` from php by using function [umask](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask), but as noted in the documentation, it's not recommended because of posibillity of unexpected behavior in multithreaded webservers.

For understanding what is `umask` and how it works for example in Debian Linux, please refer to [Debian Wiki - Permissions - The defaults for new files and directories](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#The_defaults_for_new_files_and_directories), or [Arch Linux Wiki - Umask](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Umask).

My advice for handling this situation is to make best effort for setting up permissions when creating directory / file, and **after creating, make sure to set proper permissions using [`ssh2_sftp_chmod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-chmod.php) function**.

In this case, that would be

```
/* Create directory */
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/home/site',0774);

/* Make sure proper permissions are set */
ssh2_sftp_chmod($sftp, '/home/site',0774);
```